# Swift: Bind enum case with type. Factory use case

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am trying to create a simple factory of objects using an enum. The enum case defines the kind of object that the factory needs to create.

I would like to have a single method that gets the enum and returns the instance. The challenge here is to have a way of "binding" the enum case with the type of the object it has to create.

The alternative is to have one method per class being created, like: `getMessenger()`. In that case I wouldn't need enums at all. But I want to give the enum a try.  Thanks!

What I have tried so far:

```
class ModuleFactory {
    
    enum Module {
        case messenger
    }
    
    static func get<T>(module: Module) -> T {
        switch module {
        case .messenger: return Messenger(api: API(), configuration: Messenger.Configuration(enabledMenuOptions: [])) as! T
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is appropriate to use enums here. Let's say I have another enum case `anotherModule`, and I have `let e = Bool.random() ? Module.messenger : .anotherModule`. What type would `get` return if I did `get(module: e)`? The compiler can't tell!

Comment: I would just do the alternative you described - have one method for getting each type of thing, unless you have a _really_ good reason for doing this that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper. I think you are right, avoiding the enum would allow more flexibility since there wouldn't be a one-to-one relation between enum and factory output. In any case it would be nice to know if it is possible to have a kind of "associated type" for the enum, dependent on the case.

Comment: No; you can't tie associated types to values in this way (since enum cases are values, not types themselves). There are places where this would be useful; this example really isn't one of those, though. What you've built here can be much better implemented as either a `shared` static instance, or default parameters. Factories are very rarely useful in Swift. What you're looking for is likely related to a feature called "dependent types" where a type can depend on a value, but Swift doesn't have that feature (and I expect won't get it; it's a pretty complex feature).